# Looking for an ELT tool to extract data from Woocommerce (Orders, Products, etc...)

Tags: data-extraction, woocommerce, etl

why is it so difficult to find a proper tool that helps with the data extraction from Woocommerce.
I am looking for something like Stitch.io to be able to automate the data extraction from our woocommerce shop.
I have checked and many offer only the clickbait page which shows Woocommerce as a connector but it does not really exist...

like fivetran for example...

What I resorted for now to doing was:

Use a plugin to export regularly changed elements in the backend into a csv on a sftp
Use stitch to consume those files

It is not ideal so I would rather just have stitch load data directly from the backend.

Comment: How about Meltano with https://github.com/hotgluexyz/tap-woocommerce